# Ubuntu 16.10 in Docker 1.12 claims there is no socket for MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, docker

I am now using Docker for Mac and Docker is

`Docker version 1.12.0-rc4, build e4a0dbc, experimental`

and I am trying to install MySQL in Ubuntu 16.10.
(Do not ask me, why I don't use the official one!)

The installation process is

#### run Docker

`docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.10`

(and install vim)

#### update & upgrade apt-get

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`

#### apt-get mysql-server

`apt-get install -y mysql-server`

#### dump /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

#### dump /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
...
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
```

#### find /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

```
# ls /var/run/
lock  mount  utmp <- there is no "mysqld" directory
```

Why I am making this mistake for several times and cannot use MySQL... ><

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access mysql from your host system, your problem is that you aren't exposing port 3306 when you run the ubuntu image:

you need to add this to the run command:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 3306:3306 ubuntu:16.10
```

Can't imagine why you aren't using one of the usual mysql images, though you'd still have to expose the port.

Comment: Oh really thanks I could use `mysql` command now ! But I also have a new problem !! I will post it later !